# Do 'configuration environments' exist in Play 2.x?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

In Play 1.x, you could define a different configuration for production and development enviornment:

```
# These are applied in the default 'dev' enviornment.
db=mem
mail.smtp=mock

# The following are only relevant if 'play id' = prod
%prod.db=mysql://prod@db.us.com/
%prod.mail.smtp.host=in.mailjet.com
%prod.mail.smtp.user=mailuser
%prod.mail.smtp.pass=pass
%prod.mail.smtp.channel=ssl
```

Does Play 2 have something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't exist but instead you can tell play to use a specific configuration file (you can have a "prod" file that can include a base configuration file and override only the needed properties for example).

See the section "Specifying alternative configuration file" in this documentation page : http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ProductionConfiguration